# How can I protect dynamic "create credential" statements from injection?

Tags: .net, t-sql, sql-injection

I need to make a CREATE CREDENTIAL statement in .NET with credential name, identity, and password passed in from a user interface. A naive implementation would look like this (please forgive the VB):

```
Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = c.CreateCommand
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE CREDENTIAL [" & credentialName & "] WITH IDENTITY = N'" & identityName & "', SECRET = N'" & password & "'"
```

It works, but it's vulnerable to SQL injections. I tried to use parameters like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE CREDENTIAL [@CREDENTIALNAME] WITH IDENTITY = @IDENTITYNAME, SECRET = @PASSWORD"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREDENTIALNAME", "myCred")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDENTITYNAME", "Tyler")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", "SecretPassword")
```

But I'm getting the error *Incorrect syntax near '@IDENTITYNAME'.* I've tried different combinations of brackets / no brackets, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Did you try removing the brackets around @CREDENTIALNAME?

Comment: Yes, tried that. CredentialName isn't the problem, it fails in the same way even if I use string concatenation for that part.

Comment: +1, interesting question! I question whether it's a good idea to permit back-end credential creation with a vulnerable interface... Why do untrusted users need to be able to create DB credentials?

Comment: The expected users are trusted, but you can never be too careful. Besides, even a trusted user can have a legitimate password with an apostrophe in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATE CREDENTIAL` takes a credential name, not a string or expression.

You may want to explore the [Credential.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.credential.create%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) method.

Comment: +1 This seems correct. Use the object, do not concat a string into the script.

Comment: I probably won't verify this answer because getting a hold of that namespace would be awkward for me, but it certainly looks correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can accomplish this easily. If you're intent on creating a dynamic script. 
The `CREATE CREDENTIAL` method is intended to be used by trusted admins.

Your dynamically creating it seems tricky because the typical answer of "make a stored procedure" doesn't apply here. Ideally you should use the object model in the accepted answer... However if you cannot use that object model for whatever reason you will need to scrub the parameters somehow.

What about limiting the length of your parameters? This isn't fool-proof but should get you most of the way.
Another possible  way is to search in your parameter strings for "query words" like `SELECT` or `UPDATE` etc... the presence of those words could cause a rejection of the parameters.

A more complicated way might be to try and run the parameters with a lower-level account (without the rights to `CREATE CREDENTIAL` first, in a transaction.
If there is no injection then you would expect only a single failure, if there was an injection you can expect different results... then roll the transaction back.

My opinion, though, is that you ought not allow this functionality to be exposed to potentially untrusted users.